# What is Adobe Device Central?

Tags: air, adobe

I am reading documents which related to air, mobile ... author recommend software Adobe Device Central, I try researching available products of Abobe (https://creative.adobe.com/products) but I can't see it, it's necessary? If Adobe dropped it, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Device Central has been discontinued: http://www.adobe.com/products/devicecentral.html

If you want to develop for mobile devices using Adobe Air then you have to take Adobe Flash. The HTML/JavaScript version is not available for mobile development. Instead you have to use Phonegap as Framework.